# How should I understand this function call?

Tags: c++, oop, object, reference, mfc

I've been studying C++ only for some time until now (though I spent a lot of time on learning C years ago), so my question may sound simple to experienced programmers, but I couldn't find an answer to it yet:

I'm working myself through a [sample project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301275/Chatting-using-CSocket), which implements a client-server-based chatting application to exaplain Windows socket programming.

There's a function call used to make the server wait for connection requests:

```
m_Server.Accept(m_Server.m_Client)
```

The Accept() function is declared in the CAsyncSocket class:

```
virtual BOOL Accept(
    CAsyncSocket& rConnectedSocket,  
    SOCKADDR* lpSockAddr = NULL,  
    int* lpSockAddrLen = NULL);
```

There is no separate declaration of an Accept() function in the code, which would overwrite this declaration, so the second and third parameters would be just assumed to be NULL, as these are the defined default parameters. (So I think that it's not relevant that the function is declared as **virtual** in this context.)

The objects m_Server and m_Client are both types of the class ServerSocket, derived from CSocket, which is derived from CAsyncSocket (MFC standard classes).

Now, coming to my question: Both of these objects are separately created and there's no hierarchic relationship between them. So how should I understand the function call **Accept(m_Server.m_Client)**? What is the correct terminological expression for this usage of the point operator / what does it do exactly here / what is the concrete parameter resulting from **m_Server.m_Client** in this case?

[The code can be downloaded from codeproject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301275/Chatting-using-CSocket): m_server is defined in ChatServerDlg.h and m_Client is defined in ServerSocket.h

I'd really appreciate an explanation on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be easier to answer if you would tell us what in particular you didn't understand from that code.

Comment: _"what is the concrete parameter resulting from m_Server.m_Client in this case?"_ The member variable `m_Client` from the `m_Server` instance.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I think he said that the m_Server and m_Client are separately created objects of the same type ServerSocket. From what I understand the question is, "how is it possible to call the function Accept, with an argument m_Server**.**m_Client?". The dot indicates a member, but in this case, m_Client is not a member, but a separate object. c128linux , is this what you are asking?

Comment: If I would read my question, I would also guess that the answer should be be "a member variable m_Client from the m_Server instance" (and wonder why someone would ask something so trivial). However, the m_Server instance does not have a member variable m_Client, and as  Cos pointed out correctly, I wanted to express using my bad English that m_Client is a separate object instead, defined at a different place. So that's what I also guessed, there are two different objects being referred to, which don't have a hierarchical relationship with each other as it seems.

Comment: Therefore: What is the resulting parameter, if the point operator is put between two separate objects? Looking at the function's definition, I would assume that m_Client and m_Server would be valid and necessary parameters for the first and second parameter of the function. But they are not separated by a comma, which is how two parameters would be passed.

Comment: @c128linux Have a read at my answer. There is a member variable within the CServerSocket class named m_Client. I believe it's what prompted your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer to your question.

It seems that there is a naming confusion between the object you have created **m_Client** and a member variable inside the class **CServerSocket** which uses exactly the same name (*CServerSocket::m_Client*).

I downloaded the project you mentioned, and this is the definition of the class CServerSocket.

```
class CServerSocket : public CSocket
{
// Attributes
public:

// Operations
public:
    CServerSocket();
    virtual ~CServerSocket();

// Overrides
public:

    CDialog * pDlg;
    CClientSocket m_Client; // <- CONFUSION!!!
    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CServerSocket)
    public:
    virtual void OnAccept(int nErrorCode);
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

    // Generated message map functions
    //{{AFX_MSG(CServerSocket)
        // NOTE - the ClassWizard will add and remove member functions here.
    //}}AFX_MSG

// Implementation
protected:
};
```

So if we where to create an object of type CServerSocket, then we would have access to it's member m_Client. For example:

```
CServerSocket m_Server;
m_Server.m_Client.Send(...args...);
```

This is fine! Your confusion however, arose from the fact that you created another object of the type CServerSocket called m_Client!

```
CServerSocket m_Client;
m_Client.m_Client.Send(...args...);
```

This is still fine! Weird naming convention, but legal.
So the argument **m_Server.m_Client** from the function call **Accept**, uses the member *m_Client* of **m_Server** and not the object **m_Client** that you / or the author of the original code created.

Hope this clears it up, and it's the answer you where looking for.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the answer I was looking for, thanks a lot! And sorry if it was a bit difficult to understand what I actually wanted to ask. As you said, the naming used for this sample project was the main reason for my confusion.